Datalist behavior in browser that does not support it?
I am developing some HTML for a program which uses Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF), specifically CefSharp.
The exact functionality I want is already perfectly handled with use of datalist elements: an input where the user can free-type and enter any value, but as they type suggestions from a list of expected values can easily be selected to autofill. It also handles finding similar entries i.e, if you type "red" you are suggested "red onion", and if you type "onion" you are also suggested "red onion"
However, it appears that datalist is not supported.
I am wondering if it would be possible to emulate the behavior of a datalist linked input using JavaScript? The select tag isn't appropriate for this case because free-typing new values will be just as common as selecting a pre-existing value.

It says there that it should be available in CefSharp 102, and the current version is 124. So is this still an issue?

@Barmar I am unsure what version the program is using. The program is licensed and we do not have access to see or modify source code like that. They recently updated from CEF1 to CEF3, but datalist is not working.

Have you considered a polyfill? E.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/datalist-polyfill

@amaitland Unfortunately I just tried and this is not working either.

Did you adjust or remove the feature detection in the polyfill?
